# PHP7: Catch Division by Zerro Error

Tags: php, error-handling, php-7

Is it possible to catch a Division by Zerro Error in PHP7? Now I get a warning.

```
try {
    $a = 1 / 0;
} catch (Error $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: You can't catch it because it's not an exception. It's a warning.

Comment: Its always a good idea to [**look in the manual first**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the division operator doesn't throw exceptions even in PHP7, as far as I can see.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yes I don't know the RTFM. But maybe you can make an example which is working. In my case it does not throw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the `/` operator doesn't throw exceptions, if the operands are numbers. In the case when a number is being divided by zero, the operator [only logs a warning](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/85b9055a86c946a99e2fc0923c3c7ae509691d80/Zend/zend_operators.c#L1142). Although, it [does throw an error exception](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/85b9055a86c946a99e2fc0923c3c7ae509691d80/Zend/zend_operators.c#L1190), if the operands are of unsupported types.

You can convert warnings into exceptions with a [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), e.g.:

```
class DivisionByZeroException extends ErrorException {}

set_error_handler(function ($errno, $string, $file, $line, $context) {
  if ($errno === E_WARNING && $string === 'Division by zero')
    throw new DivisionByZeroException($string, 0, $errno, $file, $line);
  throw new ErrorException($string, 0, $errno, $file, $line);
}, E_WARNING);

try {
    $a = 1 / 0;
} catch (DivisionByZeroException $e) {
  printf("Caught division by zero: %s at %s line %d\n",
    $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    printf("%s\n", $e->getMessage());
}
```

*Output*

```
Caught division by zero: Division by zero at /tmp/1.php line 11
```

Answer (score 5):

From php7 you can use [`intdiv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php) instead.

> If divisor is 0, a `DivisionByZeroError` exception is thrown. If the
>   dividend is PHP_INT_MIN and the divisor is -1, then an ArithmeticError
>   exception is thrown.

```
try {
    $a = intdiv(1, 0);
} catch (Error $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: He can use `intdiv()` in his own code. But if he wants to handle the use of `/` operator in third-party libraries, he has to setup an error handler, at least until PHP begins to throw exceptions for the operator as well.

Comment: well, to be fair the question isn't "how can I correctly use broken library?"; what if one of those third-party overwrite your error handlers?

Comment: Then he'll have another issue, and probably will post another question.

Comment: I didn't know this command. Thx. But is this a fixing of a broken thing in PHP? Every other language throws an exception in case of division by zero.

Comment: php throws just a warning for historical reason. you're right, php _should_ throws an exception if the divisor is 0, and perhaps in future it will. `intdiv` was introduced to makes the language more complete

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a=10;
$b=0;


// for php 5 
try{

    if ($b==0.0) {
    throw new Exception("Devide By Zero Exception");

    }else{
        $c = $a / $b;
    }
}
catch (Exception $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage();
}

//  for php7

try{
    $c=$a/$b;
}
catch(Throwable $t){
    printf("Type: %s<br>", get_class($t));
    printf("Message: %s<br>", $t->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: I have tried the PHP7 version. The line `$c=$a/$b;` still logs the 'Division by zero' warning with PHP version 7.0.13.